# Pass objects from main Activity to IntentService

Tags: android-intent, android-service

I have a main Activity which launches an IntentService class SchedulerWebSocketService.class

```
Intent webSockIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SchedulerWebSocketService.class);
startService(webSockIntent);
```

The service runs a web socket client. Based on the message received, the app will interpret the message, launching a background thread to begin a new task, such as taking a picture. The main Activity contains a variety of parameters, which need to be passed to the IntentService and then to the new runnable threads.

I know I can use the putExtra to transmit a few objects, such a strings. How do I pass a reference to the current Activity or other custom objects, which are shared between the main Activity and the new thread, which is launched by the IntentService?

Is there a way to somehow modify the constructor of the intent service and pass the argument to this new constructor when I call new Intent(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to pass big objects is to [bind to the service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding): once you do that your Activity will get access to the actual service and you can call methods on the service and pass it objects.

Comment: Thank you Femi, this seems like the right way to go about this.